# OSX Yosemite Kernel Panic with Wimax Modem

Tags: network, macos, usb, kernel-panic

I have upgraded to OSX Yosemite from Mavericks 10.9.4 and a very weird problem is happening. I use a Hostless Wimax USB Modem from Qubee (Wimax ISP from Bangladesh) for internet. So, there's no driver or connection manager has been required so far so use it. It has been working pretty good so far in all operating systems I use.

But After upgrading to Yosemite, If the modem is unplugged by hand or disconnected or even a very negligible disconnection happens, My Mac gets a obvious Kernel Panic and without a restart it can't be used.

Has anyone faced similar problem like this ? or any idea about it's solution. In this moment a clean installation of Mavericks is too much time killing for me.

Crash Log is as follows :

```
Anonymous UUID:       7B79C12C-F5BD-9460-72E5-5B0B3AEE8570

Sun Nov 23 00:47:27 2014

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8004c1e80a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800505bc54, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff80d5d85000, CR3: 0x0000000007a9d000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff7f87323f58, RCX: 0x00000000035d0000, RDX: 0xffffff80160bcca0
RSP: 0xffffff810edebe70, RBP: 0xffffff810edebe80, RSI: 0xffffff7f87323f58, RDI: 0xffffff80d5d85000
R8:  0x0000000000000004, R9:  0xffffff801ad7ec40, R10: 0x00002788ff391f4c, R11: 0x00002788fea0a037
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff8005310688, R14: 0xffffff80d5d85000, R15: 0xffffff7f87320cfc
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff800505bc54, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff80d5d85000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810edebb20 : 0xffffff8004b3a811 
0xffffff810edebba0 : 0xffffff8004c1e80a 
0xffffff810edebd60 : 0xffffff8004c3a443 
0xffffff810edebd80 : 0xffffff800505bc54 
0xffffff810edebe80 : 0xffffff7f87320d13 
0xffffff810edebea0 : 0xffffff80050db3cd 
0xffffff810edebf00 : 0xffffff8004b6be13 
0xffffff810edebfb0 : 0xffffff8004c192c7 
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMData(4.2.2b5)[762A4700-2305-3989-8E9B-D107BDB0A47E]@0xffffff7f8731f000->0xffffff7f87323fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[247581D8-DFC5-3AAE-B079-3D13F5514C2B]@0xffffff7f857e5000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(705.4.14)[E15E9DC8-410F-3612-8371-E5FECD939E0D]@0xffffff7f85824000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14B25

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x0000000004800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004900000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 43469341152519
last loaded kext at 41222733055284: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8735c000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 39875210719909: com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.7.0 (addr 0xffffff7f87339000, size 81920)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.18
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.1
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.filesystems.cd9660    1.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMData 4.2.2b5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.2b5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   901.19.10
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMControl  4.2.2b5
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 267.0
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1

Unable to gather system configuration information.Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM         MBP91.00D3.B08, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3430554738424255302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3430554738424255302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.10)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: WiMAX USB Card, Ethernet, en4
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST500LM012, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: WiMAX USB Card
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: ST18i
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 1):

A kernel panic in most *nix operating system is very difficult to debug. You can get hints from here how to submit a bug report http://support.apple.com/en-us/ts3742 but if you read the tech notes in the end of the article it points hints to either the OS kernel or driver causing the system to crash. The "quickest" workaround is to revert to the previous working state which unfortunately in your case is Mavericks. Sorry.

Comment: I have done the bug report several times before I posted this here :) I am editing the post and attaching my crash log.